# How to customize the C printf function in such a way that it automatically adds a message log?

Tags: c, printf

I'm developping a C project with different kind of users. For logging and debugging I would really appreciate a customized `printf` function that just adds at the beginning of the messages a label that indacates the type of users. Is it possible without rewriting the `printf` function from scratch?

Comment: you need to use vprintf and possibly a macro

Comment: use macro printf

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Out of curiosity, what aspect requires the use of vprintf? Would something be unknown to OP at time of compilation? (Other than actual text of user-type, another known). Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Ok I,ve never done that. Would you please link me some references?

Comment: @enhzflep well, basically it is possible to have a `printf` macro but it does not work if you want to use a variable to make the format string, and there are varying levels of hacks one can use, but basically the example by Kevin Boone is the easiest that actually works.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a crude example. `my_print()` is called in the same way as `printf()`, but it produces some output before processing the arguments. Of course, what that additional output is and where it comes from is something that needs to be determined in a specific application.

The significant fact is that we can provide a printf-like function without reimplementing `printf()`.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void my_printf (const char *fmt,...)
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start (ap, fmt);
  printf ("MY INFO... ");
  vprintf (fmt, ap);
  va_end (ap); 
}
  
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  my_printf ("The answer is %d\n", 42);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an addition. At least with gcc one can declare the function as `void my_printf (const char *fmt, ...) __attribute__(( format( printf, 1, 2) ));` to let the compiler know it's `printf()` like and perform argument checks

Comment: This doesn't completely answer the question as I understand it though. Replacing all existing calls to `printf` by calls to `my_printf` seems cumbersome. Maybe add a paragraph about how to use `LD_PRELOAD` to get around this.

Comment: @Peter `LD_PRELOAD` is platform specific and may not apply to the OP.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Similar mechanisms exist on basically most platforms.

Comment: I guess if you want to retro-fit functionality to an existing application that uses `printf()`, then you could perhaps make `printf` a pre-processor macro that expands to`my_printf` or whatever. `LD_PRELOAD`ing a new `printf` with the same name has the benefit, in principle, of being usable with _any_ program, perhaps even one that cannot be changed. But it requires a familiarity with development techniques that I suspect many developers won't have. TBH, it's not clear to me whether the original question was about modifying the behaviour of an existing application, or writing one.